# Android UI Layout for HD Device

Tags: android, layout, screen

Why is it so hard to have application that support all multiple screen density? Is it possible? Why some applications have separate apk for HD? E.G Angry Bird Space HD, etc

I have res/layout and res/drawable which works fine (works on phone and tablet) except on HD device. HD Devices are smart phone (4" normal sized screen) with deep density like Samsung Google Nexus 9250 and Sony Xperia S with screen resollution 720x1280 and 300+ dpi

When I added folder res/layout-xlarge and folder res/drawable-xhdpi. It works fine on HD Device but strangely on tablet the layout becomes ugly.

Why is it so? I'm expecting tablet layout will not look at res/layout-xlarge and res/drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why some applications have separate apk for HD? E.G Angry Bird Space
>   HD, etc

One reason is pricing -- common business logic would tell you that an HD version is more expensive than a regular one. And with the ease of pirating even paid apps in Android, they don't want their apk bought with a phone to run in HD on a tablet.

Another is assets and apk size. You don't want to fill your low-def version apk with hd images, as it will never use them anyway.

> When I added folder res/layout-xlarge and folder res/drawable-xhdpi.
>   It works fine on HD Device but strangely on tablet the layout becomes
>   ugly. Why is it so?

If you show us your code, I'm sure we can easily point something wrong with it. Your case can't be too special that something works for other developers but not you.

> I'm expecting tablet layout will not look at res/layout-xlarge and
>   res/drawable-xhdpi

[Then where did you expect it to look?](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Comment: Hi Josephus. Thanks for your answer. That open my mind. Anyway tablet is supposed to be mdpi not xhdpi. I finally make it works by adding res/layout-mdpi, res/layout-hdpi and res/layout-xhdpi. Strange thing here my Galaxy Tab comes into hdpi which from density 170dpi it should be mdpi device. I did not add /res/drawable for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. This is why when I only added res/layout and res/layout-xhdpi it works on HD device but on Galaxy tab it looks ugly. It seems like Android automatically adjust to nearest dpi possible. Any further explanation on this?